# Trouble with Snapshot tests in CDK

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cdk, ts-jest

I am trying to do some snapshot testing on my CDK stack but the snapshot is not generating.

This is my stack:

```
export interface SNSStackProps extends cdk.StackProps {
  assumedRole: string
}

export class SNSStack extends cdk.Stack {
  constructor(scope: cdk.Construct, id: string, props: AssumedRole) {
    super(scope, id, props)

    const topicName = "TopicName"

    const topic = new sns.Topic(this, topicName, {
      displayName: "Topic Name",
      fifo: true,
      topicName: topicName,
      contentBasedDeduplication: true
    })

    const assumedRole = iam.Role.fromRoleArn(
      this,
      "AssumedRole",
      props.assumedRole
    )

    topic.grantPublish(assumedRole.grantPrincipal)
  }
}
```

This is my snapshot test

```
test("Creates an SNS topic ", () => {
  const stack = new Stack()
  new SNSStack.SNSStack(stack, "SNSStack", {
    env: {
      account: "test_account",
      region: "test_region"
    },
    assumedRoleArn: "arn:aws:iam::1111111:role/testRole"
  })
  expect(SynthUtils.toCloudFormation(stack)).toMatchSnapshot()
})
```

This generates a snapshot with an empty object like this

```
exports[`dlq creates an alarm 1`] = `Object {}`;
```

Why is the object empty in the snapshot? And how do I get the Object in the snapshot to populate with the resources in my stack?

Comment: I think the snapshot you shared is not related to the test you shared since they have different names. I think it's useful to name the snapshot too. `.toMatchSnapshot('your snapshot name here')`

Answer (score 0):

You should create a `Stack` by using an `App` and not another stack. You can then easily synthesize the `App` and extract the JSON cloudformation stack which you can use for your snapshot. Below is an example of how I've used it to create the stack and retrieve the CloudFormation.

```js
const app = new App();
new ApiStack(app, 'api-stack', params);
return app.synth({ force: true }).getStackByName('api-stack').template;
```

It is possible that once you've got the stack reference, you can use the `SynthUtils` way to get the CloudFormation repository.